# Detect file opening error on Lua

Tags: lua

I'm using Lua on iOS and I'm having problems to open a file with `io.open("filename.txt","w")`, I know that I'm receiving nil, but is there any way to detect the failure reason and try to solve it according to that? something like errno of C?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#pdf-io.open):

> #### `io.open (filename [, mode])`
>
> This function opens a file, in the `mode` specified in the string mode. It returns a new file handle, or, in case of errors, **nil** plus an error message.

An example usage using the second value returned from the function is as follows:

```
local f, err = io.open("filename.txt", "w")
if f then
    -- do something with f
else
    print("Error opening file: " .. err)
end
```

If the process does not have permission to open the file, for example, the following message will be printed out:

> Error opening file: filename.txt: Permission denied

Comment: I'd like to add that it is *very* important to check the return value of `io.open` before writing anything to the file; actually, if it returns `nil` and you pass this `nil` value as file handle for writing, Lua5.2 segfaults.